# GCP AutoML Vision - How to count the number of annotations each of my team members makes in GCP AutoML Vision Annotation Tool using the Web UI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-cloud-automl, automl

We are automating the process of our deep learning project. Images are automatically uploaded to a dataset in AutoML Vision (Object detection) in the Google Cloud Platform. We have a couple of team members who regularly annotate the uploaded images by using the provided Annotation Tool in Web UI. We need to measure the productivity of our team members by counting the annotations they make for each of them. I haven't found an efficient solution yet. I would appreciate it if you could share your ideas.

Comment: It is not very clear the service you are using, title says AutoML and the description says AI Platform. Both products have different subservices. Please share more details (and documentation if possible) on how you are annotating the images.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a feature to identify who annotated which images; however, the approach I can think of is that you can split the work between your team members and distribute the labels that each one should annotate. Then you can simply count the number annotations for each label. For instance, in [from this guide](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/label#annotating_images_via_the_web_ui) you can give `Baked Goods` and `Cheese` to one collaborator and `Salad` and `Seafood` to another one, and so on, so that you can check the totals in the UI. Even, the [label statistics](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/label#view_label_statistics) can give you more details of annotations for each label (hence for each team member), note that statistics are only available in AutoML Vision Object Detection UI.

An automated approach, in case you are interested in, is [Human Labeling Service](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/label#human-labeling); according to documentation, currently, it is only available [by email](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/data-labeling/docs) because of the Coronavirus (COVID-19) measures

If recommendations above don't fit your needs, you could always file a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) for asking the desired functionality and add the required details.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess I can't use this trick, since whenever someone annotates an image then it is set as a "labeled image". It will be painful for others to check every image in "labeled images" section every time they start annotating. I will file a feature request. Other than that, is it possible to write a javascript script to the browser console, so that it listens to button clicks and counts each of them as a single annotation?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible to modify the GCP Console's behavior to add functionality from the End User. I know that Developer Tools can be used for debugging purposes which includes [insert JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console#javascript). With Devtools you can even [change the HTML](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/edit-html-in-the-console-panel), but I'm not quite sure that this can help for your purpose.